# Query Kafka Streams state store within a time range

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to query a Kafka Streams state store based on time range. The use case is that I'll have the streams processor be scheduled every 30 seconds. During each invocation, I want to query a state store but for only the entries which are "new". I thought TimestampedKeyValueStore might help but couldn't find the right APIs to do it. Is it possible to query the state store based on time range (and with exactly-once guarantee)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot query a `KeyValueStore` base on a time range, because this does not really align to the semantics of the store. Queries are always against the key, and a `TimestampeKeyValueStore` stores an additional value-timestamp.

You could use a `WindowedStore` though: note, a windowed-store is basically also just a key-value store, however, it store a timestamp next to the key (*not* the value; well, there is also `TimestampedWindowStore` that also does both). This allows you to query time ranges.

**Update**

In upcoming Kafka 3.7 release, new query type are added, that will allow you to do more advanced queries. In particular, `VersionedStateStore` will support time-range queries (cf [KIP-968](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-968%3A+Support+single-key_multi-timestamp+interactive+queries+%28IQv2%29+for+versioned+state+stores) and others).